# Elasticsearch S3 repository missing exception

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-2.0

I am using ES 2.X. I am using AWS Cloud Plugin.
I have scheduled jobs to take snapshot of my cluster everyday.
My jobs were running successfully and I have snapshots of my cluster of last two days.
Today my job is throwing the following error :
`repository_missing_exception`.

I checked the repository details using the following commands :

```
http://10.xx.xx.xx:9200/_snapshot/my_repository
```

I am getting the details as follows :

```
{
  "my_repository": {
    "type": "s3",
    "settings": {
      "bucket": "elasticsearch-backup",
      "region": "us-west-1"
    }
  }
}
```

I am not able to understand what is the issue ?

I am using Java program to take snapshots ,  please refer the code :

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
data.put("ignore_unavailable", true);
data.put("include_global_state", false);
data.put("compress", true);`

WebTarget target = client.target("http://"+Host+":"+Port+"/"+"_snapshot"+"/"+Repo+"/"+snapShotName+"?pretty?wait_for_completion=true");

target.request().put(Entity.json(data));
```

Comment: What is the command running for taking the snapshot?

Comment: I am not using `curl` command. I am using Jersey as follows :

`JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
            data.put("ignore_unavailable", true);
            data.put("include_global_state", false);
            data.put("compress", true);`

`WebTarget target = client.target("http://"+Host+":"+Port+"/"+"_snapshot"+"/"+Repo+"/"+snapShotName+"?pretty?wait_for_completion=true");`

`target.request().put(Entity.json(data));`

Comment: Please update your question with that, it'll be more legible

Answer (score 1):

I ran into same issues earlier and possible reasons could be, check if these works out for you :

- the platform where the ES hosted might not have access to S3 , please assign the right role to access the s3 bucket , this holds good for both ES hosted on EC2 or AWS open search . This might have thrown similar issues while registering the repo or something could have changed in between causing this issue.
- Once the plugin is installed , a reboot of the node might be required.